# Esconder botões de CRUD em templates do Django para os usuários que não estão logados no sistema

Tags: django, autenticação, django-templates

Gostaria de esconder os botões do meu sistema que permitem: adicionar, editar e deletar os dados dos meus templates para os usuários que não estão logados no sistema. Ele pode ser visto aqui: https://sirh-marcellobenigno.herokuapp.com

Após algumas consultas, vi que pode ser feito dessa forma:

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    ...
    <button>...</button>
    ...
{% else %}
...
{% endif %}
```

Porém, serão adicionadas várias condições aos templates... teria alguma forma mais elegante de fazer isso?

Comment: Tive um problema parecido no `Laravel 5`. A solução que tive foi criar o botão numa view só, onde eu passava os parâmetros para criação do botão. E daí, lá mesmo já tem a verificação se o usuário tem acesso ou não.. Só tenho o trabalho de incluir, o de verificar não...

Comment: Interessante... quais eram os parâmetros nesse caso? acho que pode ser uma saída sim.

Comment: Bem, no meu caso eu fiz da seguinte forma: `@if(auth()->user()->canAccess($rota))link_to_action($rota, 'adicionar', isset($params) ? $params : []`) @endif`

Comment: Deve estar difícil de entender. olha esses [gist](https://gist.github.com/wallacemaxters/6114eb2fe53ebd98d1c6926ebd54c38b) que fica mais fácil

Comment: Valeu @WallaceMaxters, vou tentar por aqui.

Comment: É mais fácil você só passar o nome da url ou rota, do que passar e verificar ao mesmo tempo.

Comment: É uma pena que eu tenha mexido tão pouco com esse excelente framework do Python :D

Answer (score 1):

Consegui, seguindo a dica que foi passada. reaproveitei a lógica nos templates, a partir de includes, da seguinte forma:

```
 {% include 'partials/actions.html' with pk=basin.pk detail='basins:detail' edit='basins:edit' delete='basins:delete' %}
```

e no include:

```
<a href="{% url detail pk %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" role="button">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" aria-hidden="true" title="Ver"></span>
</a>

{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}

    <a href="{% url edit pk %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" role="button">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true" title="Editar"></span>
    </a>
    <a href="{% url delete pk %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" role="button">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true" title="Deletar"></span>
    </a>

{% endif %}
```